# How to set JSONArray in model class?

Tags: android, arrays, json, model

How can I set JSON array to model class? I am trying to add but its giving error.Can anyone help me to so

```
 offerlines = new ArrayList < Offerlinemodel > ();
 Offertextlistmodel olms = new Offertextlistmodel();
 JSONArray offerLine = joofer.getJSONArray("offerLine");
 olms.setOffertextmodel(offerLine);
 offertextlist.add(olms);
```

Comment: What is `Offertextlistmodel` ? is `setOffertextmodel` taking `JSONArray`  as param ?

Comment: What kind of error does it give?

Comment: Post your json string

Comment: this is what i have in my model class 

 ArrayList<Offerlinemodel> offertextmodel;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help

Create a model class and set Offertextmodel as JSONArray

```
public class  Offertextlistmodel {

    JSONArray Offertextmodel;
    public void setOffertextmodel(JSONArray Offertextmodel)
    {
        this.Offertextmodel = Offertextmodel;
    }

}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!